# Play Framework authentication: request headers are not being added in production

Tags: deployment, playframework, playframework-2.0, request-headers

I have implemented an authorized action as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39865650/play-framework-authentication-in-a-single-page-app) as well as the answer by @vdebergue.

This was working great, and the requests made by the front-end application were automatically adding an X-XSRF-TOKEN request header, with the token obtained from the login response.

However upon deploying both front-end and back-end, the requests issued from the browser are no longer adding the X-XSRF-TOKEN request header, thus causing an Unauthorized response from the server (rightfully so).

What I am failing to understand is, what is it that changed between development and deployment?

I do have the request header specified in cors.allowedHttpHeaders:

```
play.filters.cors.allowedHttpHeaders = ["Accept", "Origin", "Content-Type", "X-XSRF-TOKEN"]
```

I doubt I have to add this header manually from React (in fact the issue probably has nothing to do with the front-end).

Thanks!

Edit 1:

List of XHR requests:

[image: list of XHR requests]

Details of the login POST request, can see the X-XSRF cookie and the token being passed:

[image: details of the login POST request]

Details of the unauthorized GET that is not setting the X-XSRF as request header:

[image: details of the unauthorized GET]

Same as previous screenshot, but running on localhost, getting authorized with the header added:

[image]

Comment: It does not seem really clear where the issue is coming from. Can you check that the browser is sending the requests correctly in dev and prod environment ? 
If so, are there additional layers in prod between the frontend and backend, like a reverse proxy ? And what version of play are you using ?

Comment: Not totally sure how you're providing the token but looked like you may be using a cookie? I wonder if it's a cookie domain issue? if the cookie domain is not on the same domain as the SPA, then it may ignore the XSRF cookie value?

Comment: @vdebergue I am able to do a POST login request. the response contains the cookie. no domain is specified. I also tried various types of domains (with/without http://, with/without port number. trying different things because i recently ran into Play CORS issue where both http and port number had to be specified to work, and "*" did not)

I do have a reverse proxy on the backend to run Play on an Apache base.
Also, using Express to run the React app.

Play version is 2.6

yes i'm using a cookie indeed. Front and backend are both on same domain different ports.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you implemented correctly, and the cookie is not attached during deployment, the issue might be related to the ***domain*** of your cookie. The way I did it is to define an an env variable and use it to hold the domain value; so it does not break the implementation during development and tests.

You can look at the [Playframework API documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.Cookie) for more information on how to use the cookie.

Comment: Would you please emphasize "assuming you implemented correctly"?  Implementation is exactly as in the link provided in the question.  I tried various domain values as per your link to the docs (khorkhe@domain.com, http://khorkhe@domain.com, khorkhe@domain.com:8080 etc.), and I can see the cookie domain in the login response. The request header does not get added.

Comment: @Khorkhe your cookie domain should be `.domain.com` if your app is running on `app.domain.com`. If the problem still exists could you copy/paste the header responsefrom your browser?

Comment: sorry for the delayed response. I have added screenshots with all the details requested, under *Edit 1*

Comment: @Khorkhe the difference I see is that the cookie is not attached, and as I said in my answer is because your cookie does not have any domain. What is the line in controller that has `Ok(...).withCookie(X)`.. What is the X in your code?

Comment: here it is: `result.withCookies(Cookie(AuthTokenCookieKey, token._1, None, domain = Some(".hatem.ws"), httpOnly = false))`. You can see in the second screenshot (login), the "Set-Cookie" line does indeed have the domain, as you suggested in your answer above

Answer (score 0):

Solved in an unconventional matter: front end was made with react, which offers a way to build a **static** production version.

I simply integrated those static files with play framework's index.scala.html, instead of trying to run it as a separate app on a different port.

It works, however i will not mark it as a best answer yet, because i don't know whether a mobile app connecting to the same play framework backend will play along nicely when it comes to authorisation and cookies. Mobile apps are not browsers (and maybe don't abide by their limitations), and Postman had no issues with cookies.

To be checked.